# DNN 9.8 - EventLogController is obsolete - Does anyone have an example on how to use the Dependency Injection method to fix this error?

Tags: error-handling, dotnetnuke, dnn9

Does anyone perhaps have an example to replace the old Error logging in DNN module?

I have looked at the following articles:

1. https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/1527
2. [Has anyone implemented DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Portals.IPortalAliasInfo.HttpAlias in DNN version 9.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790246/has-anyone-implemented-dotnetnuke-abstractions-portals-iportalaliasinfo-httpalia)

I currently get the following error:
[image]

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
      EventLogController logController = new EventLogController();
      logController.AddLog("Problem Getting Product Description, Title, or Image URL.", ex.ToString(), EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT);
    }
```

Do you need to create a startup file?
If so, do you need to create a startup file for each module or put it in the root folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that works for me:

```
using DotNetNuke.Abstractions;
using DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace myCompany.DNN.Modules.myModule {
   private readonly IEventLogger _eventLogger;
   public class myControl {
      public myControl() {      // this is the constructor of the class
         _eventlogger = DependencyProvider.GetRequiredService<IEventLogger>();
      }
   }

   protected override void someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      try {
         // some code
      } catch(Exception ex) {
         _eventLogger.AddLog("Problem Getting Product Description, Title, or Image URL.", ex.ToString(), EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT);
      }
   }
}
```

And this [article](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dnn-dependency-injection-webforms-modules) could be useful, too...