# Cannot instantiate implementation type 'DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging.IEventLogger' for service type 'DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging.IEventLogger'

Tags: error-handling, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am trying to replace all the Deprecated EventLoggerController code in my DotNetNuke (DNN) Modules.

I had a look at an answer someone posted on a previous question I had and also another question asked by someone.

1. [DNN 9.8 - EventLogController is obsolete - Does anyone have an example on how to use the Dependency Injection method to fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307883/dnn-9-8-eventlogcontroller-is-obsolete-does-anyone-have-an-example-on-how-to/71319023#71319023)
2. [Why am I getting the error "Cannot instantiate implementation type" for my generic service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987892/why-am-i-getting-the-error-cannot-instantiate-implementation-type-for-my-gener)

I also had a look at this article regarding DNN webforms using Dependency Injection:
https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dnn-dependency-injection-webforms-modules

[image]

I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have added a Startup.cs file to my DNN module project:
[image]

I have added the following code to my code behind file:

```
private readonly IEventLogger _eventLogger;

public View()
{
  _eventLogger = DependencyProvider.GetRequiredService<IEventLogger>();
}
```

[image]

Logging the exception:
[image]

I assume something is wrong with my Startup.cs file.

Comment: What is your actual question? Are there any errors after your changes? Or is it simply not logging? I suspect you have to change the two lines in your last code snippert, because as far as I understood it Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException() will end the code and return. So the line with the logging will not be reached...

Comment: So the issue I am having is that even before it reaches a breakpoint near my catch on my module, I get a "Cannot instantiate implementation type 'DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging.IEventLogger' for service type 'DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging.IEventLogger'." when I load any page without the module. I think it has something to do with the startup.cs file I added for that particular module. The startup.cs file is not in the root of the DNN site, but under the specific DNN modules folder.  I think this code is perhaps wrong: DependencyProvider.GetRequiredService<IEventLogger>();

Comment: Then I would try to add a try-catch construct around this line and see what happens...

Comment: I have added a try-catch to the Startup.cs file, but I see it never throws an error in the catch. I have even checked the Page_Load method and it also does not go in the catch. The page loads with the message "Cannot instantiate implementation". Do you perhaps have an example of your Startup.cs file?

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. I am using a WebForm DNN module and I don't need a Startup.cs file yet. It seems that it will be added to DNN version 10 and up if I understand correctly. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a DNN module that uses WebForms and it seems like it does not require a Startup.cs file yet. It seems that it will be added from DNN version 10 and up.

I also had a look at this forum question: https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/2002