# How to add the DNN Event Logger Depedency Provider to a custom Controller Class that Inherits the DNNAPIController Class?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have a custom Controller Class in my WebForm DNN Module and would like to replace the Deprecated Event Log code with the new Event Logger code.

Here is an answer on how to use the new Event Logger Code: [DNN 9.8 - EventLogController is obsolete - Does anyone have an example on how to use the Dependency Injection method to fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307883/dnn-9-8-eventlogcontroller-is-obsolete-does-anyone-have-an-example-on-how-to)

I can get the new Event Log code to work on a normal View.ascx.cs page because it Inherits from the PortalModuleBase class.

My Controller Class needs to Inherit the DNNAPIController class. I can't Inherit the PortalModuleBase as well, because you can't Inherit more than one class in C#.

How can I get this to work on my Controller Class?

[image]

[image]

DNN PortalModuleBase (You will see that the property is protected)

[image]